# How do I format this nested for loop pyramid to look like how I need it to?

Tags: c, nested-loops

I am practicing nested for loop exercises and want to make a program that prints something like this:

```
How many rows do you want?: 4
    0
   000
  00000
 0000000
```

Here is my program so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int x;

  printf("How many rows do you want in the pyramid? (newlines included): ");
  scanf("%d", &x);

  for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    printf("\t");
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        break;
      }
      printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My code works like I would like it to, but it outputs the pyramid like this:

```
How many rows do you want in the pyramid? (newlines included): 6
0

000

00000
```

How do I format it to look like an actual pyramid instead of a right angle triangle as it is now? Also I am aware there are other ways to do this but I tried to use my creativity with this practice exercise.

Comment: The blank lines are because you skip every other row with `if (i % 2 == 0) { break; }` Apart from that you need to print some leading spaces on each line, and calculate the required number of `0` characters.

Comment: Here's a tip: use printable characters like `_` or `x` in place of spaces at first. They're easier to count, easier to see where you are or aren't printing what you need.

Comment: Another tip: count the number of `0`'s and spaces on each line. How do those numbers relate to the row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to skip lines in order to print an odd number of zeros. Use `2*i+1`.

`2*i` will always be an even number, so `2*i+1` is always an odd one.

Now you just need to add space before to print the zeros. To do that you use another loop which prints less spaces as `i` grows bigger. You could use the condition `x-i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int x;

    printf("How many rows do you want in the pyramid? (newlines included):\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j < x-i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < 2*i+1; j++) {
            printf("0");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```